# How to check if files exist from list of urls in Google Spreadsheet?

Tags: google-sheets

Assume that I have a list of URLs, each URL returns code 200 or 404.

How can I extract HTTP response code from these URLs?

Is there a function like `importHTML`, but it checks response code only?

```
 |A                              |B                       |
-+-------------------------------+------------------------+
1|URL                            |response code           |
-+-------------------------------+------------------------+
2|http://example.com/huge1.tar.gz|=importHTMLResponse($A2)|
3|http://example.com/huge2.tar.gz|=importHTMLResponse($A3)|
4|http://example.com/huge3.tar.gz|=importHTMLResponse($A4)|
...
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would have to right a proxy service to a known url then

```
importHTMLResponse(http://MYPROXYSERVER/reponsecode?url=$A2)
```

or something similar.
The proxy service would run what ever language you are comfortable with and just hit the supplied url returning the status code.